# ExtJS different builds for different clients

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-cmd

We currently have a number of clients using our ExtJS 4 based application.

We would like to inc/exclude various pieces of code/components depending upon which client the build is for.

Is this possible with ExtJS?
Has anybody else approached this before?